# How to redirect at Api Gateway level given a specific query string parameter value?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

We are using serverless and we deploy an API with a few lambdas that return some information.
Those lambdas have authorizers and process information from some external API.

Our FE retrieves the API gateway URL from our BE (which is a plain .NET monolithic server),  so basically our architecture consists of 3 parts: FE, BE and Microservices in API GW.

The MicroService calls include an Id that identifies one entity in our system, and that's used to retrieve info from our external API

That works well, and it's running in production; however some of those external APIs are not reliable enough for us, and we have a big demo coming up and we wanted to mock those external APIs, but just for one specific case (meaning, for one specific Id)

My idea was to create a fake lambda, but I am unsure how to redirect it without changing the code. Can this be done on API gateway console? Basically, if they Id (in querystring) is X, redirect the new lambda, otherwise, just let everything flow as it is. Is there a way to achieve this redirection completely on API gateway level? or in serverless.yml configuration at worst

Our goal is to be able for a specific entity, in production, to hit a fake lambda of ours (instead of our lambda that hits the external API) so we can return mocked data with the proper structure. Given there are multiple stages (dev, QA, staging, prod) we were looking something easy just for our demo, without having to change any production-ready lambda or code in the FE or BE (nor introduce a risk for any other entity)

tl;dr: how can I redirect at API gateway level/configuration (no code) to another lambda given a specific value in a query string?